# Uploading/Downloading files via SFTP to/from remote location via KSH script

Tags: shell, sftp, ksh

I have a java program that is to be run like a batch (at specific times during the day) and a Unix Shell Wrapper that needs to contain the code to trigger the batch and then transfer the output files of the program (via SFTP) to a remote server location. Similarly it also has to fetch a file from the remote location and 'pull' it onto our server again via SFTP.

My query is how to transfer the files via SFTP to/from the remote location?
Also, in case there is any failure/error in transferring the files, I need to perform some error handling like raising notifications etc.
 I have to write the commands in a Korn Shell script. I do not have a background in shell scripting and have been looking up tutorials and forums to help me find a solution but I still don't have one. I have seen solutions suggesting using batch files for sftp or using something like 
    sftp $user@$host <<< 'pwd' > /dev/null 2>&1 but I don't think the second command does what am looking for and am at a loss.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have way to many questions, please split them to separate posts.

Comment: Hi, I have just one question through the post - My query is how to transfer the files via SFTP to/from the remote location.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have set up ssh keys you can run this batch mode without user input (password).  IT is called a here document:

```
 cd /path/to/output
    /usr/bin/sftp user@remote.com <<-EOF
      cd /path/to/remote/directory
      put  file1
      put  file2
      put extra_files*
      exit
EOF
```

How to set up ssh keys with ssh-keygen:
http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html